# Error while downloading Android Studio SDK

Tags: android, android-studio, android-sdk-tools

This is the error I am getting:

> java.io.IOException: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Connection reset
>   , response: 200 OK
>   Warning: An error occurred while preparing SDK package Android Support Repository: Cannot download 'https://dl.google.com/android/repository/android_m2repository_r47.zip': Connection reset
>   , response: 200 OK.

[image: Bug screenshot]

Comment: Are you able to download those files manually by putting those addresses into a web browser? Is this constantly happening, or just happening once?

Answer (score 4):

you can try this:

1. run Android Studio as Administrator
2. run the update again

It should work.